# The Dimension of Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Question:
Let $A$ be an $n×n$ complex matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Let $V$ be the set of all $n×n$ complex matrices $B$ that commute with $A$. Prove that V is a vector space and find its dimension (Justify your answer).

My Answer: I know how to show that V is a vector space, but I don't know how to find its dimension.
I tried showing that if v is an eigenvector corresponding to some eigenvalue, so is Bv, and got that for all B, Bv = kv for some scalar v. But I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: (Note that you didn't finish stating the question.) Hint: can you find the dimension of $V$ if you assume that $A$ is diagonal? Further hint: can you reduce the general question to the case where $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: There should be a post on this site addressing this question.  That being said, it helps to start by considering the case where $A$ is a diagonal matrix

Comment: @Omnomnomnom when you say that there should be a post on this site addressing the question, would you be able to link that post? I've also edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I'll link it if I find it, but I haven't found it yet.  The question looks familiar though

Comment: Also, we have proven before that if A is a nxn complex matrix with n distinct eigenvalues then A is diagonalizable, so I'm not quite sure how to take your hints.

Comment: @GaloisFriend We're telling you to focus on the following question: if $A$ is **actually** a diagonal matrix, which is to say that
$$
A = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \ddots\\ && \lambda_n}
$$
with the blank entries denoting zeros, then which matrices $B$ commute with $A$?  See what the actual matrix-multiplication looks like.

Comment: Alright, so the matrices B must all be diagonal matrices as well in order to commute with A.

Answer (score 4):

You have proved that $Bv_i = \mu_i v_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$.

Let $p$ be the polynomial such that $p(\lambda_i)=\mu_i$.

Then $p(A)v_i=p(\lambda_i)v_i=\mu_i v_i=Bv_i$.

Therefore, $B=p(A)$.

Thus, $V$ is exactly the subspace of all polynomials in $A$. What is the dimension of that subspace?